# Send unicode string to server socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, unicode

**I read other SO questions about this problem and nothing solve my problem so I think this post is not a duplicate.**

I want to send a Unicode string from android client socket to a server socket But I receive all Unicode character as question marks from server (I use a c# server on windows). I use WireShark to monitor network and it show all Unicode character as dots. This is my send code:

```
String msg = "تست سوکت";

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
    true);

out.println(msg);
out.flush();
```

Some stackOverFlow question says adding `charSetEncoder` to `OutputStreamWriter` constractor can solve this but that's not worked for me and the result was the same:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), 
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder())),
                true);
// Or
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), 
                        "UTF-8")),
                true);
```

After that I try to send byte array as string, But that send nothing to server:

```
byte[] byteArray = msg.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
out.println(byteArray.toString() + "\n");
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the java client code and not in the server C# code?

Comment: 'After that I try to send byte array as string,'. That is not a good idea. You should send the byte array itself. So you cannot use println(). Use write(). Experiment with msg.getBytes. And you should show the receiving C# code of course.

Comment: @Gavriel The problem was in server code but result from wireShark make me believe it's client problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your tip. I keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code is correct.

That Wireshark is not showing unicode characters is assumable a limitation of Wireshark.

Therefore the receiving C# program must be the problem. Are you sure that this program expects a stream of UTF-8 characters? 
"Unicode" on Windows and C# usually means UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: I use `state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));` in my server to read content and I just change it to `state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));` and everything works fine. thank you so much.